# Show hidden files inside neovim in windows

Tags: windows, neovim

I am beginner to vim stuff. And I am currently using neovim in my windows machine. But I noticed that files with dot(.) extension at beginning are hidden + folders listed in .gitignore are also hidden. Is there any easy way to unhide those files and folders.

I searched for solution in internet and many of them are for linux. I cannot find way to do it in windows

Comment: Vim and Neovim don't know about `.gitignore`. Also, *where* are those files "hidden"? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: They are not showing inside neovim file tree, it just shows 5 hidden items

Comment: Quick google suggests pressing `H` to show/hide hidden files.

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich, but  I have to unhide every time when I open new window, is there any way to permanently show all items

Comment: https://github.com/nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim/discussions/353

Comment: FWIW, Vim's own netrw shows hidden files by default and NERDTree needs one line of config to do so. The more convenient those tools become, the less usable they are...

Comment: @romainl bro check once before commenting. The folders/files listed in .gitignore are hidden by default in neotree

Comment: Not by Vim or by Neovim, *bro*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use H (Shift + H) to see the hidden files in the file explorer for neovim.